# Android Переключение между фрагментами

Tags: android, android-fragment

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите как сделать переключение между фрагментами. Есть 3 фрагмента. на которых размещены кнопки. Как через кнопки сделать переключение между фрагментами?

Код activity(Задаю фрагменты):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
/** идентификатор первого фрагмента. */
public static final int FRAGMENT_ONE = 0;
/** идентификатор второго. */
public static final int FRAGMENT_TWO = 1;
/** идентификатор третего. */
public static final int FRAGMENT_THREE = 2;
/** количество фрагментов. */
public static final int FRAGMENTS = 3;
/** адаптер фрагментов. */
private FragmentPagerAdapter _fragmentPagerAdapter;
/** список фрагментов для отображения. */
private final List<Fragment> _fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
/** сам ViewPager который будет все это отображать. */
private ViewPager _viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // создаем фрагменты.
    _fragments.add(FRAGMENT_ONE, new FirstFragment());
    _fragments.add(FRAGMENT_TWO, new SecondFragment());
    _fragments.add(FRAGMENT_THREE, new TherdFragment());
```

.....

В классе фрагмента на котором расположена кнопка пишу переход на другой фрагмент:

```
public class SecondFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
private Context context;

Fragment fragment1;

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //задаем разметку фрагменту
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second, container, false);
    //ну и контекст, так как фрагменты не содержат собственного
    context = view.getContext();

    fragment1 = new FirstFragment();

    //Knopka 1
    Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.pager, fragment1);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

}

В итоге происходит переход на пустой фрагмент.

Comment: у фрагментов есть кстати метод getContext()

Answer (score 1):

как я понял вам нужно переключать текущую страницу ViewPager. для этого у MainActivity дописываем метод

```
public void setPage(int page) {
    _viewPager.setCurrentItem(page, true); //второй параметр для плавного перелистывания
}
```

и перелистываем страницу из фрагмента:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity).setPage(MainActivity.FRAGMENT_ONE);
```

Comment: Да то что нужно. Огромное спасибо.  Всего 3 сточки :). 2 дня инет курил из за этого :)